# Post edited ng-grid field to server

Tags: ajax, angularjs, ng-grid

I am unsure how to send a post with the edited field from Ng-grid back to the server in order to update the database.

This is the code that I am trying to use. However, nothing is loging to the console.

```
<script language="JavaScript">

var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngGrid']);
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.cellEditTemplate = "<input style=\"width: 90%\" step=\"any\" type=\"text\" data-ng-class=\"'colt' + col.index\" data-ng-input=\"COL_FIELD\" data-ng-blur=\"updateEntity(col, row)\"/>";


    $scope.myData = midas.foo;

    $scope.gridOptions = {
        data: 'myData',
        enableRowSelection: true,
        enableCellSelection: false,
        enableCellEditOnFocus: true

    };
    $scope.updateEntity = function(column, row){

        console.log(row.entity);
        console.log(column.field);
    };


});</script>
```

Comment: Can we see the markup and the contents of midas.foo ?

Comment: Its just a json...the grid shows just fine. I just dont know how to run the edits :)

midas.foo = [{"name":"Moroni","age":50}];<

Answer (score 0):

It basically works like this:

```
$scope.$on('ngGridEventEndCellEdit', function(grid) {
   alert(grid.targetScope.row.entity.name)
});
```

Here is an [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/bV2Xgx?p=preview)

Comment: How can I give/get the ID of the row that was edited as well?

Comment: By adding some kind of UID to your data? How else will you ever be sure the entry that was just edited is the one that will be updated in your db?

Comment: Is it possible to have a hidden column in the data?

Comment: You don't need to hide a column. Just leave it out of the columnDefs. Look here: http://plnkr.co/edit/RlAzWV?p=preview